# convert "denormalised" hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I am working with a file that has "denormalised" keys in it, and have read it into a hash.

The hash looks like this in part:

```
:primer_left_0_sequence=>"TCCTTCCTGCAGCCATGAAG",    :primer_right_0_sequence=>"GGCCTCGGCACTTACTTCAT", :primer_left_0=>"90,20", :primer_right_0=>"195,20", :primer_left_0_tm=>"60.035", :primer_right_0_tm=>"60.108", :primer_left_0_gc_percent=>"55.000", :primer_right_0_gc_percent=>"55.000"
```

Later there are the same keys repeated, but with a different embedded number in the key:

```
:primer_left_2_sequence=>"TTCTCTCCCTCCTTCCTGCA", :primer_right_2_sequence=>"GGCCTCGGCACTTACTTCAT", :primer_left_2=>"81,20", :primer_right_2=>"195,20", :primer_left_2_tm=>"59.883", :primer_right_2_tm=>"60.108", :primer_left_2_gc_percent=>"55.000",
```

It repeats several times, and each time the integer embedded in the key could be different.
I would like to load this data into a table, where column names are the same as the keys, but without the integer embedded. Each time there is a new set of repeating information, I will insert a new row.

Something like this, but I can't work out how to deal with the integer embedded into the key:

```
rawfile_hash.each do |key, value|
  # if a new key integer, then create a new record
  # ie: primer3_output = Primer3Output.new
  if primer3_output.class.accessible_attributes.include?(key)
    primer3_output.send("#{key}=", value)
  end
end
```

**EDIT**

Just to be clear, I am looking for the code to do in effect something like this:

```
primer3_output = Primer3Output.new    
primer3_output.primer_left_sequence = rawfile_hash[:primer_left_0_sequence]
primer3_output.primer_right_sequence = rawfile_hash[:primer_right_0_sequence]
... many entries later ...
primer3_output.save
primer3_output = Primer3Output.new
primer3_output.primer_left_sequence = rawfile_hash[:primer_left_2_sequence]
primer3_output.primer_right_sequence = rawfile_hash[:primer_right_2_sequence]
... etc ...
```

**SOLUTION**

If this is re-opened I'll add it as an answer.

As a rake task

```
namespace :db do
  task load_table: :environment do
    results = []
    row = 0
    File.open(Rails.root.join("lib", "assets", "P3_INPUT_577_8328_1197.raw"), "r").each_line do |line|
    key, value = line.strip.split("=")
    id = key.scan(/\d+/).first.to_i
    column_name = key.gsub(/_\d+/, "").downcase
    results[id] = {"primer3_parameter_id" => id} unless results[id]
    results[id][column_name] = value
    if id > row
      PrimerPair.create!(results[row])
      results[row] = nil
      row = id
    end
  end
  PrimerPair.create!(results.last)
end
```

end

Comment: Give us an example of what the column names should be.

Comment: Added more detail under EDIT

Comment: I added a description under the edit... the source data has an instance number embedded in the variable name, and I just wanted to extract the variable sans the instance number, with each iteration of the instance as a new object. See the EDIT section. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its hard to gauge exactly what you want to do, but from what I can gather from you question this should work;

```
rawfile_hash.each do |key, value|
  # if a new key integer, then create a new record
  # ie: primer3_output = Primer3Output.new
  key.gsub!(/_\d+/,"") # simple regex
  if primer3_output.class.accessible_attributes.include?(key)
    primer3_output.send("#{key}=", value)
  end
end
```

**EDIT**

Re: your comment below — You could include an extra column in the db and find or create the record by that value, that way you can still sort by it. Something like this;

```
i = key.gsub(/[^0-9]/,"").to_i
key = key.gsub(/_\d+/,"")
Primer3Output.find_or_create_by(:i => i)
```

Comment: That looks pretty good thanks. I still need to work out how to insert  a new row when the integer within the hash is incremented... and will need to somehow sort the hash by that embedded integer. Whew! Thank for your answer.... I will play with the code a bit.